# How to detect video seek start

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I am using VideoView, MediaPlayer provides "setOnSeekCompleteListener" to detect seek completion but I would also like to detect seek starts.

Is there a way to detect seek start?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I over-rode "void seekTo(int pos)" to detect seek start and detected seek end using "setOnSeekCompleteListener".

```
//    @Override
public void seekTo(int pos)
{
    Log.d("MyApp", "Seek started from " + getCurrentPosition())
    // Perform Task and calling parent class implementation of "seekTo"
    super.seekTo(pos);
}
```